# Wicket Panel destructor (Java)

Tags: java, wicket

Does Wicket notifies a Panel when this Panel is removed/replaced in the Page?

I add JavaScript (initialization code) in Panel's constructor and need to release some resources when Panel is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Later versions of Wicket (1.4.0+) have Component#onRemove() method, which is needed to notify the component that it's being removed from the component hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

There is also PubSub system at the client side where you can do what you need.
See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax#WicketAjax-GlobalAjaxcalllisteners and event '/dom/node/removing'.